# Set date of installed files with WiX

Tags: wix

Is it possible to from the wix-project set the timestamp of Files?

I am thinking like:
    `<File Id='id1' LastModified='2015-11-26' />`
or
    `<File Id='id1' LastModified='[Now]' />`

Comment: Begs the question of "why?" but Aaron Stebner had a [use case and solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2013/05/23/10421023.aspx).

Comment: We have some unversioned files without obvious CompanionFile.
At the moment we solve it by running a pre-build-script running touch...

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way using wix file element, no attribute that specify the version.
You can check all the attribute in:
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/file.html

This open source project contain many useful scripts and build custom activities, the link below is for the prebuild script.
https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions/CustomActivities/tree/master/Source/Scripts